# Do click/onclick not work for touchscreens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a website to display information in the form of a table. The user can click rows on the table to change their color, and I also have a button that allows the user to pause the refreshing of the page so that no new information is added. Both of these functions work on desktop, but not on touchscreen. My first idea was that a touch on a touchpad wasn't considered a click, but after researching this that theory doesn't seem to be true. When I run this on my desktop it works just fine. Where am I going wrong?

Update: I have found some sources saying that click will not work, but some still say it will work on a 300 ms delay. I'm still not sure which is right, but assuming that click/onclick will not work for touchscreens, what would be some good alternatives?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeOut 
    var timeOutInter = 10000;
    setRefresh(timeOutInter);
    $("#hdTable")
        .children("tbody")
        .children("tr")
        .children("td")
        .click(function () {
            $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("active");
        });
});

function enableRefresh(t) {
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, t);

    if ($("#pause").text() == "CONTINUE") {
        $("#pause").html("<a href='#' onclick='pause()'>PAUSE</a>");
    }
}

function setRefresh(t) {
    enableRefresh(t);

    // Control the pause button
    $("#pause").click(function () {
        if ($("#pause").text() == "PAUSE") {
            $("#pause").html("<a href='#' onclick='pause()'>CONTINUE</a>");
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        } else {
            $("#pause").html("<a href='#' onclick='pause()'>PAUSE</a>");
            enableRefresh(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Update 2: None of the solutions provide have worked on the tablet so far, so I downloaded the Jquery mobile library and the tap function from it. My code now looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var timeOut 
var timeOutInter = 10000;
setRefresh(timeOutInter)
$("#hdTable").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").on("tap", function () {
      $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("active");
});
```

});

```
function enableRefresh(t) {
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, t);

    if ($("#pause").text() == "CONTINUE") {
        $("#pause").html("<a href='#' onclick='pause()'>PAUSE</a>");
    }
```

}

```
function setRefresh(t) {
    enableRefresh(t);

    // Control the pause button
    $("#pause").on("tap", function () {
        if ($("#pause").text() == "PAUSE") {
            $("#pause").html("<a href='#' onclick='pause()'>CONTINUE</a>");
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        } else {
            $("#pause").html("<a href='#' onclick='pause()'>PAUSE</a>");
            enableRefresh(t);
         }
    });
}
```

This once again works on my desktop, but not the tablet. The mobile library is supposed to work with pretty much any touchscreen. I'm at a loss now.

Update 3: Added eventListener to the code. I used the line
    $("*")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
which worked on desktop, but not on tablet. I other keywords instead of click like touchstart and touchend, vclick, and tap. Getting no response at all from this on tablet is more than a little odd, but I'm not sure where to start looking into this.

Comment: You can use `$('#pause').on('click touchstart', function() { });` and it should work on all devices.

Comment: @KRONWALLED I replaced `$("#pause").click(function () {}` with your suggestion, and this didn't work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Touchscreen devices will respond to

```
elem.addEventListener('click', functionName, false);
```

but there is a 300ms delay while the device waits to see if the tap becomes a double-tap.

There are several methods to disable the delay:

**See:**

- **[What Exactly Is..... The 300ms Click Delay](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-exactly-is.....-the-300ms-click-delay)** by *TJ Van Toll* (Nov 21st, 2013)
- **[5 Ways to Prevent the 300ms Click Delay on Mobile Devices](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/)** by *Craig Buckler* (Jan 8th, 2014)

Comment: In terms of my pause control, I'm a little confused as to where this is supposed to go. I had initially assumed it would go in `$(document).ready` in place of setRefresh. I wrote it as `$("#pause")..addEventListener('click', setRefresh(timeOutInte), false);`, however this threw a "function doesn't exist" error. The only other place I think I could put it could be in setRefresh, but I didn't think calling the $("#pause").click(function () {} would work. Would you mind clarifying? Sorry for the trouble, I am very new to jQuery

Comment: `addEventListener` isn't from the `jQuery` library - it's standard `javascript`. I keep meaning to crack on and learn `jQuery`... but I haven't started yet, so `javascript` is all I know at this point.

Comment: I'm sorry to say addEventListener didn't work for me, even when I applied it to the whole web page.

Answer (score 0):

So I have no idea why, but the problem was internet explorer. When I switched to google chrome, both suggestions I received worked just fine.